# Infinite scrolling and search with RTK query duplicate results

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll page of posts with search. It works with Reddit JSON API.
There is no pagination in common sense. Reddit api returns listings. Listing JSON responses contain after field which is equivalent to the "next" buttons on the site and in combination with count can be used to page through the listing. So the first request is made without after param and all the following ones contain 'after' with if from the previous server response.
When I change search request, I clean the after state.

This is my rtk api:

```
export const postsAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'posts/api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.reddit.com/',
  }),
  endpoints: build => ({
    getPosts: build.query<ITransformedPosts, { limit?: number, searchParam?: string, after?: string }>({
      query: ({ limit = 8, after, searchParam }) => ({
        url: searchParam ? 'search.json' : '.json',
        params: {
          limit,
          ...(after && { after }),
          ...(searchParam && { q: searchParam })
        }
      }),
      serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName, queryArgs }) => { return queryArgs.searchParam || endpointName },
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        currentCache.posts.push(...newItems.posts)
        currentCache.after = newItems.after
        currentCache.hasMore = newItems.hasMore
      },
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg
      },
      transformResponse: (response: IPosts) => ({ posts: response.data.children, 
after: response.data.after })
    }),
```

It works fine, except one bug. If I make search request and make the same afterwards, new data are concated to the previous ones. So there are doubled posts.

Are there any chance to say rtk: "Hey rtk, if there are data on the particular request, first return the existing data. And concat new data only when I sent the same request with new 'after' param.